# boost regex install from source library not linking - osx

Tags: c++, macos, boost, linker

I am using the boost libraries for a project, and I am running into issues with the regex library.  I am re-installing the libraries because I have upgraded to osx 10.9 (mavericks).

I am getting 2 undefined references for :

```
boost::match_results<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > >::maybe_assign(boost::match_results<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > > const&)
```

and

```
boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::construct_init(boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > const&, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags)
```

---

I am installing the boost libraries from source, specifically because I do not want to be using macports or any outside package installer.  The reason is that my program is used in the mathematics and scientific community, and I am trying to keep it so that it can easily compiled from source with the appropriate dependencies (i.e. linking to certain libraries like gmp and mpfr, and, at least for now, boost).

The undefined reference issue is occurring regardless of the compiler I've used.  That is, I have installed gcc 4.7.3 with apple's default compiler from the command line developer's tools.  So this occurs for both gcc4.7.3 AND the default g++ (apple's clang, version 4.2.1).

This is a parallel application, so I have two versions of mpich3 installed, both compiled with the above 2 compilers and installed and built in separate directories.

When I built boost, I edited the `user-config.jam` file and added the lines

`using gcc : 4.7.3 : "abs\loc\here" ;`

and

`using mpi ;`

Then I ran `sudo ./bootstrap.sh ; sudo ./b2 ; sudo ./b2 install` (with the sudo being necessary as the installation files are in a /usr/local subdir)

Anyway, the file that is using the boost libraries is called para_aux_funcs.hpp / para_aux_funcs.cpp, and I am compiling with (well, after a Makefile that produces this for me to make all .o files from the .cpp ones ):

```
/usr/local/mpich3-mac-default/bin/mpic++ -cxx=/usr/local/bin/g++ -I/Users/matthewniemerg/Research/Bertini/Current/BertiniSource_v1.4/include -I/usr/local/boost_1_50_0/include -I../include -Dtimingstep2 -DTIXML_USE_STL -Wall  -O3  -funroll-loops -fexpensive-optimizations   -fopenmp  -c para_aux_funcs.cpp -L/usr/local/boost_1_50_0/lib -lboost_regex -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem  -o para_aux_funcs.o
```

I've also done this with the other mpi installation with the appropriate -cxx flag passed to indicate which compiler was used for the mpi compilation.  And, I've also switch the order of where the -L and -l flags go in the above command, but with the same results.

That is, the following command gives me the undefined references indicated above:

```
/usr/local/mpich3-mac-default/bin/mpic++ -cxx=/usr/local/bin/g++ -I/Users/matthewniemerg/Research/Bertini/Current/BertiniSource_v1.4/include -I/usr/local/boost_1_50_0/include -I../include  -Dtimingstep2 -DTIXML_USE_STL -Wall  -O3 funroll-loops -fexpensive-optimizations   -fopenmp  -o paramotopy paramotopy.o point.o datagatherer.o failed_paths.o menu_cases.o master.o slave.o step2readandwrite.o runinfo.o mtrand.o random.o step2_funcs.o step1_funcs.o timing.o tinyxmlerror.o tinyxml.o tinystr.o tinyxmlparser.o  xml_preferences.o para_aux_funcs.o ../lib/libbertini_osx9.a -lm  -lmpfr -lgmp    -L/usr/local/boost_1_50_0/lib -lboost_regex -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem
```

This looks like a linking error, but I am linking the libraries (i.e. -l flag) and pointing to the appropriate directories for where the library is located (i.e. -L flag) and indicating where the appropriate header files are (i.e. -I flag).

Any thoughts / ideas?

Comment: Boah! That long, really?? TL;DR;

Comment: just being thorough in the explanation!

Comment: @user3220798 May be edit your question to enhance readability (my edits aren't really helpful with that long horizontal scrollbars, try breaking lines reasonably). Also other stuff might be worth to be highlighted. All in all try to nail your point for the reader, what's your final problem and why you don't expect it should occur for your situation.

Comment: I wonder if your boost is getting built with clang/libc++ instead of gcc/libstdc++.  On Mavericks, `g++` is clang.

Comment: @Marshall, I thought that this might be the issue as well.  I thought changing the user-config.jam file would change what compiler is used for the build.  

It's not clear (or maybe I couldn't find it) how to specify clang/libc++ vs. gcc/libstdc++.  How do I do that?

Comment: @nagniemerg - try specifying the toolset when building boost, like this: `b2 toolset=gcc`. If you want, toss in a `d+2` for verbose messages, and make sure that you're getting what you expect

Comment: I followed the directions here : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/boostusers/VwjHBjfl2vI and this seemed to work, at least with removing the linking error.